# How do I automatically exit a bash script that ends with a less

Tags: bash, less

How can I send a keystroke like 'q' to a script that ends with a call to less?

test.sh

```
ls -l | less
```

If I call test.sh it hangs and waits for the user type 'q'. How can I do something like this:

```
echo 'q' | test.sh
```

And have the script exit?

Comment: Did you try that exact thing? Did it work?

Comment: yes, it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, which still have less page the output, but it will exit when it hits eof.

```bsh
LESS=-E ./test.sh
```

or

```bsh
./test.sh | cat
```

which just dumps the output to the screen.